# Symantec Endpoint Protection 11 Issues

Tags: broadcom, symantec

SEP 11 is preventing me from using a couple of utilities on a Windows 2008 R2 64 bit server. Mainly Broadcom NIC utility for NIC teaming. I find if I configure the server the way I want and then install SEP11 I am fine until a reboot then I lose network connectivity and some drives that are connected through Netapps SnapDrive. Has anyone every experienced this or have a recommended way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issues with Broadcom NIC's and teaming in past conversations. One solution is to modify the SEP install and remove the NTP module. You can do this from Add/remove programs.

This issue has been discussed here - https://www-secure.symantec.com/connect/forums/sep-v11-broadcom-teaming-issue

Let me know if this was helpful.
Best, 
Thomas (Symantec)

Comment: Hello Thomas, unfortunately that fix did not work. I did make some progress by being able to team two nics because I could not do that at first with SEP11 installed and NTP enabled. The teamed IP address is still unreachable